# Lost email account for Apple ID

Tags: iphone, ios, email, apple-id

I just bought a new iPhone. I had an old Apple account with a lot of data but I don't remember my email. Do I have to create a new account for using my new iPhone, losing all my data? Is there a way to restore my email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've forgotten the email address for your Apple ID, you can use one of the recovery emails in the account at https://iforgot.apple.com.

If you don't have any recovery email addresses and can't remember the original Apple ID email address, you can't recover your account.